# How to select last N records from a table in mysql

Tags: mysql

This code can be used to select the first ten records from a table in mysql. How can I do the same to display last ten records from a table which has 1000 records. I want to display the name in asc order dont want to change that.

```
   SELECT name, cost FROM test orderby name asc LIMIT 10 ;
```

Comment: it's either order by name, or by date inserted/unique id.

Comment: It depends in what sense do you mean last N records - in the order of their names or id or date or cost or anything else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT q.name, q.cost
    FROM (SELECT name, cost
              FROM test
              ORDER BY name DESC LIMIT 10) q
    ORDER BY q.name ASC;
```

Answer (score 3):

The `LIMIT` clause can take two parameters, which will provide an offset:

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned
>   by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments,
>   which must both be nonnegative integer constants (except when using
>   prepared statements).
>
> With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the
>   first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of
>   rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1):
>
> SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15 To retrieve all
>   rows from a certain offset up to the end of the result set, you can
>   use some large number for the second parameter. This statement
>   retrieves all rows from the 96th row to the last:
>
> SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 95,18446744073709551615; With one argument,
>   the value specifies the number of rows to return from the beginning of
>   the result set:
>
> SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5;     # Retrieve first 5 rows

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

So with this:

```
SELECT name, cost FROM test orderby name asc LIMIT 990, 10;
```

Comment: What happens when a row is inserted and the table now has 1,001 rows total?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT name, cost
FROM (SELECT name, cost FROM test orderby name desc LIMIT 10) as test
ORDER BY name asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ROW_NUMBER() clause for this, this will be helpful for you

select **top** "N" * from (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order by Col_Name desc) as RowNo,* from  Table_Name) Table_Name